# Social Exchange bot Stuck at button click

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, click

I am trying to build a simple web-bot in python for `addmefast` but i am currently STUCK on the step where the bot is supposed to click on the Like button inside `addmefast.com`

I keep getting the same results:

```
Likebutton = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("single_like_button.btn3-wrap > div.btn3").click()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'
```

Part of the code that gets stuck:

```
driver.implicitly_wait(4)
YTlikespage = driver.get("h t t p : / / addmefast . com/free_points/youtube_likes")
Likebutton = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("single_like_button.btn3-wrap > div.btn3").click()
```

The Code that leads to the button seems to be the following:

```
<a class="single_like_button btn3-wrap" onclick="openFbLWin_2180739();"><span> </span>

<div class="btn3">Like</div>


</a>
```

Changing the `elements` to `element` makes the program not be able to locate the element at all.

Comment: Your selector must be wrong if find_element_by_css_selector() doesn't find what you're looking for. Provide the HTML and someone may be able to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`find_elements_by_css_selector()`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_elements_by_css_selector) returns a list of elements, while you need [`find_element_by_css_selector()`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.find_element_by_css_selector) which would return you a single element:

```
like_button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".single_like_button.btn3-wrap > div.btn3")
like_button.click()
```

Also note the dot at the beginning of the selector.

Comment: Updated Main post with more details

Comment: @user3812335 thanks, you were just missing a dot at the beginning of the CSS selector - updated the answer.